# Temporary files causing explorer.exe to behave oddly and use excessive CPU time

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, cpu, windows-explorer

Since I built my computer a couple months ago, I noticed that explorer.exe is constantly using about 10-15% CPU at idle. I finally discovered that the source of the problem is most likely some program writing things to the temp folder, since when I clear it out and restart my computer explorer behaves normally for a few minutes before CPU use spikes again. If it makes a difference, the high CPU usage only seems to occur on a single core.

Similarly, explorer will often refuse to refresh automatically when files are moved or renamed, necessitating me refreshing it several times over the course of relatively simple operations, something that I think is also related to whatever is in the Temp folder, since this issue doesn't occur after I clear it and restart.

My system specs are:

AMD Ryzen 5 3600XT (6-Core)

32 GB DDR4 3200 MHz RAM

booting from a 256GB Samsung NVMe drive

NVIDIA RTX 2060 Super, if that matters at all

I'm running the most recent update of Windows 10, but this issue has persisted across all version of Windows 10 I have installed on my current computer.

Comment: If you boot into a minimal boot configuration does the behavior still exhibit itself?

Comment: I would disagree with the concept the "temporary files" are somehow to blame.  That is nonsense.  To further what @Ramhound is pointing out.. you probably either have some junk as a startup program, a third party shell extension, or a service dumping junk there on a timer.  If all also fails, you can use the system internals process monitor to determine WHAT is dumping the files in temp but I can *almost* assure you that dumping files there is not the real problem.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - Depending on the amount of I/O it could explain the CPU usage.

Comment: @Ramhound, you misunderstood me.  It was his title inferring that temp files are the problem based on very circumstantial evidence.  Lots of programs use %temp% so without following your initial advice (or my procmon advice) we won't know. Of course I/O could explain the CPU usage and that I/O might very well be in the temp directory.

Comment: Open up your task manager and go to the details tab, first sort by CPU and watch for the problem to happen.. if you can't see it, right click on an empty column and choose "select columns"  Add I/O reads and I/O writes.  Sort by writes and repro the problem.  No luck? Sort by reads and try again.  You might be able to narrow down the culprit this way too.  Of course, you will probably need to do your reset trick between each try.